# Why is it giving me an error when i'm calling it from inside the 'student class?

Tags: java, string, debugging, printing, integer

*I have to Create a class called student

**but I'm getting an error and I didn't know how to complete the code, but
what I did is:**

```
public class Student {

String name;
private int age;
private int grade;
private int average;
private String disability;

public void StuInfo(){
name = "John";
age = 15;
grade = 71;
average = 63;
disability = "No";

    
System.out.println("Name: "+name+",Age: "+age+",Grade: "+grade+",Average: "+average );
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    StuInfo();
}
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Hi and welcome! In general you need to describe the error and what was expected. Some tips that will make your program compile: You need to create first a new object of the class Student or make the stunInfo() method static. (The java convention for method names is to start with a lowercase later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to successfully compile your program you need to create first a new object of the class Student or make the stunInfo() method static.
Also the java convention for method names is to start with a lowercase later, so StunInfo should better be named 'stunInfo'. A name like 'printStudentInfo()' can be considered, which  would be even more readable and better shows what the method does.(Improves readability)
These notes can get your example working but it is not a complete solution to the homework posted. You need perhaps to change the access modifier of the stunInfo() method to be only accessible from within the class etc.

```
public class Student {

String name;
private int age;
private int grade;
private int average;
private String disability;

public void Student(){
  name = "John";
  age = 15;
  grade = 71;
  average = 63;
  disability = "No";
} // end constructor

public void stunInfo(){
    System.out.println("Name: "+name+",Age: "+age+",Grade: "+grade+",Average: "+average );
} //end stunInfo


public static void main(String[] args){
    //Create a new student
    Student student=new Student();
    //Invoke stunInfo method
    student.stunInfo();
} //end main

} //end class
```

Comment: How can I change the access modifier of the stunInfo() method to be only accessible from within the class? I have no idea

Comment: Replace the word 'public' in "public void stunInfo" with the word 'private'.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling non static method from static method. Create object of StuInfo by -> new StuInfo();